# using ng-keypress on a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've spent quite a bit of time looking into the ng-keypress attribute in angular.js and im not sure why this isn't working. my specific element is a canvas element although ive seen other questions dealing with other elements. The situation is attempting to put a keypress listener on a canvas element and all of the forms of adding that listener seem to work except for the ng attribute directives. here is an example of what i mean

```js
angular.element('.lastExample').on('keypress',function(event){
  alert('and so does this');
  });
```

```css
canvas{
  border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<canvas tabindex='1' ng-keypress="alert('this does not work')">canvas not supported</canvas>
<canvas tabindex='1' onkeypress="alert('but this one works')">canvas not supported</canvas>
<canvas tabindex='1' class='lastExample'>canvas not supported</canvas>
```

i already applied the trick to allow the element to be focused (the `tabindex='1'`) and using the `on` property (inherited from jquery and used in the defining of the ng-keypress directive [as shown here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62)) does work as does the html supported `onkeypress` but the ng-keypress doesnt seem to be working. does anyone know why the ng key directives don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is to do with the difference between Javascript and Angular expressions, especially with regards to the execution context. As per Angular's documentation:

> Context: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global
>   window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

Furthermore, the author goes on to clarify

> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.

Therefore, calling alert() from within the ng-keypress directive is not evaluated against Angular's execution context. One only needs to create a function within Angular's context and call that function to be evaluated in ng-keypress,

**View**

```
  <canvas id="blank-canvas" tabindex="1" ng-keypress="alertFn()"></canvas>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('CanvasCtrl', function($scope, $log) {

  $scope.alertFn = function() {
    alert("key pressed");
  }
});
```

And a working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codeapprenti/tun4urc3/

Comment: Um I'm not sure you read my question all the way through my angular.element function works (the trick to get it to work. Is to load the full jquery rather then use angular jquery lite, angular inherits from a previously loaded jquery as long as the tags are in order) my problem is that specifically ng-keypress is not working

Comment: I put it in as a code snippet so you can test it yourself the angular.element works

Comment: Updated my answer - have you tried using `tabindex="1"`? It seems to be a trick to focus on the canvas element. You can look at the updated fiddle too. http://jsfiddle.net/4k9gbawz/

Comment: I have onkeypress which works and angular.element().on which works and ng-keypress that doesn't I'm asking why the ng-keypress doesn't work while the others do.

Comment: I tried it in my fiddle and it seems to work.  jsfiddle.net/4k9gbawz

Comment: You realize script tags are commented out of jsfiddle right? And also your jsfiddle currently is not dealing with ng-key press to be honest I'm not sure what your js fiddle is showing right now

Comment: Try updating your fiddle

Comment: @Binvention Ah I know what the problem is - in ng-keypress it seems like it has to be a function defined in scope. If you use a plain javascript function it doesn't work. Try it in the fiddle?

Comment: @Binvention ng-keypress attribute is in the canvas tag. Please check again.

Comment: ng-key press takes an expression like all of the other ng event attributes.

Comment: In the top left of your js fiddle is a pencil that says update click it.

Comment: I'm still not seeing what you're seeing

Comment: can you do me a favor and start a collaboration in your jsfiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97770/discussion-between-code-apprentice-and-binvention).